# Automatically rename sheet based on cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just create a button with script to create new sheet from template, can i get the code to create new name sheet based on number id between C2:C58?

This is my code create with macro:

```
function Qfull() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J12:J13').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Q Full'), true);
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(86);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName('New Quotation');
};
```

Please check the screenshot here: [image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hey can you attach a clearer picture. Cant really see the contents to understand what you are doing w your macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I would suggest the following modifications:

1. Create a column to check if the tab has been created before something like a checker. In my example I use ColB to mark 'created' if it has already
2. Use a **forEach** loop to read through every row and check if the tab with the name in ColC has been created before. If it has not been created, create a new tab with the template 'Q Full' and renaming it with the names in ColC.

I have created an MVP to match your case: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vrZJmlkQGD-7zujf55b0oUqQ8AXdwai5MY3Rmw2076A/edit#gid=0

Regarding forEach loop: https://spreadsheet.dev/foreach-loop-in-apps-script

I would code yours as below:

```
function Qfull() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Summary 2022');  //get the sheet which you want to extract names from
  const check = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Q Full'),true); //set your template for duplication

  check.forEach(function(row,col){
    if(col == "") return;
    if(row[1] == "created") return; //if ColB shows 'created' skip

    ss.duplicateActiveSheet().setName(row[2]); //create sheet with name from ColC

    sheet.getRange(col + 1,2).setValue('created'); //after creating put 'created' in ColB so it won't create the next round

  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's really helpful!